# Run stored procedures in a loop based on a parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a function `test_function` where I am passing `_snapdt` as parameter. I want to run this function for several dates (`_snapdt`) individually in a loop.

Can someone help me with this?

For example I want to run this function for several dates like "2018-01-30" , 2018-02-30" and so on ..

Currently I am running it manually like this:

```
select * from test_function('2018-01-30') ;
select * from test_function('2018-02-30') ;
```

Here is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_snapdt date) 
RETURNS integer
AS 
$BODY$
declare rows integer;
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
create table temp_table AS
select col1,col2 
    from table1
    where id=01000 and
    snapshot_date=_snapdt
group by col1,col2
distributed randomly;


INSERT INTO standard_table
(   snap_date,
    col1,
    col2
)
SELECT 
_snapdt as snap_date,
a.col1,
a.col2,
FROM temp_table a;

GET DIAGNOSTICS rows=ROW_COUNT;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
return rows;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `generate_series()`

```
select test_function(t.dt::date)
from generate_series(date '2018-01-30', date '2018-02-28') as t(dt);
```

If you want to call the function once for each month, change the interval:

```
select test_function(t.dt::date)
from generate_series(date '2018-01-01', date '2019-12-01', interval '1 month') as t(dt);
```

Comment: I have monthly snapshot dates from 2018 to 2019 . Do i need to explicitly write all those monthly dates inside a generate series function?

Comment: @user8545255: you can change the interval of the generated dates. See my edit